# Anchor won't work when using Jquery .load()

Tags: load, anchor

There might be some similar questions to mine, but havent found anything quite the same.

Here I go:

I have a very simple jquery that LOADs a link from an external page:
Note: This DIV is set as overflow auto.

Suppose I have this DIV where I load external page list of items and at the end I put an anchor (a name="my_end_point")(/a)  - Sorry, could not make html shows here.

My Script works perfectly, however, the ANCHOR won't be triggered as expected. See below
$("#div_element").load("my_external_page#my_end_point");

I thought it was no big deal, however I'm kinda stock, and scrolling automatically to the end_point seens not to work at all.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With the way jQuery .load() works, it might be trying to pull a div with an id of #my_end_point from 'my_external_page' instead of triggering an anchor.

jQuery Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/load/

If you had two divs on my_external_page, one #firstDiv with the word CHOWDER within it, and another #secondDiv with the word SOUP in it, then .load("my_external_page #secondDiv"); would load SOUP and not CHOWDER.

To scroll to an anchor, you could use a scrollTo plugin, such as http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html